# c#: how can i save a chart and a textbox in a single image (e.g. *.png)?

Tags: c#, image, charts, textbox

Solution: Used DrawtoBitmap to draw the chart and textbox separately on the same bitmap, and saved it using bitmap.save.

Problem Description: I have code which analyses data and draws graphs saving them as a .png file. I want to add text in the .png file along with the graph chart. Is it possible to collage the chart and textbox to a single image, and save it as a single file?
Please the the graph image.png i have till now, and how i want my text to be in the same image.

[image]

Comment: This may be helpful, as it's similar to what you want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637801/c-sharp-add-a-layer-to-an-image

Comment: It seems like you need a watermark to png image?

Comment: Not the watermark, something more like collaging two object into a single image. Like 3/4th of the image would be a graph and the other 1/4th, a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a number of options:

- You can take a screenshot
- You can `Save` the `Chart`'s Image and `DrawToBitmap` the `TextBox` and then draw the 2nd image over the former.
- You can `Save` the `Chart`'s Image and `DrawString` the `TextBox.Text` over the image
- You can add the `TextBox` to the `Chart.Controls` (in code!) and then use `DrawToBitmap` to make the chart draw both into one image.
- You can `DrawString` the text in a `Chart.xxxPaint` event and use `DrawToBitmap`

The next two options make the text a genuine part of the Chart:

- (Recommended:) you can use a `TextAnnotation` or a `RectangleAnnotation`: Place it at a suitable spot on the `Chart` and use maybe the `TextBox.TextChanged` event to copy the text into the `TextAnnotation`. This is the most 'chart-like' option and most likely what I would do.
- You could even **replace** the `TextBox` by a editable `TextAnnotation`..!

**Not seeing the chart and not knowing the purpose in any detail, it is hard to recommend which way to go..**

All `Annotations` are a bit tricky to place, but will move when the chart is resized and will even be saved to xml when you serialize it. Well worth learning!

**Update:**

Here is an example that places the text right below the `Legend`, assuming it is on the default top right position.

**Note** that an `ElementPosition` contains both location and size and that all numbers are in percentages of the container, in out case of the `Chart`..:

First we declare it globally; we also could access it via the `chart.Annotions` collection but I'm lazy; also note that I use a `RectangleAnnotation`, which is the same as `TextAnnotation` but with the option of back color and border..:

```
 RectangleAnnotation RA = null;
```

To create it I use this code:

```
RA = new RectangleAnnotation();
RA.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
RA.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
chart.Annotations.Add(RA);
RaPos();
```

To place it I use a function:

```
void RaPos()
{
    if (RA == null) return;
    ElementPosition LP = chart.Legends[0].Position;
    RA.X = LP.X;
    RA.Y = LP.Bottom + 5;  // 5% below the legend
    RA.Width = LP.Width;
    RA.Height = 100 - LP.Bottom  - 10;  // leave 10% of the remaining space
}
```

We need to adapt the position at some points like here:

```
private void chart_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RaPos();
}
```

And to synch it with the textbox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RA.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

When saving all Annotations **do** get saved, unless they were placed outside the visible area..:

```
chart.SaveImage(someFileName.png, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

This annotation will always keep docked below the legend and will resize its height to fill the remaining space nicely..

Also note that by adding this: `RA.AllowTextEditing = true;` the user could **doubleclick** the rectangle and put the `Annotation` into editing mode with the need for a separate `TextBox`..

[image]

**Update 2:**

Now, as you have posted the chart, I can see that you are docking the Legend to the bottom. Of course the code would need some changes, maybe like this:

When setting it up I create some space at the right side:

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
ca.Position = new ElementPosition(5, 5, 75, 85);
```

And in the positioning I create the new ElementPosition directly so to fit in:

```
// numbers are in percent!!
RA.X = 83;
RA.Y = 8;
RA.Width = 15;
RA.Height = 80;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have added an image of the chart i have till now. Can you please have a look at the image. Also, i tried adding annotations to the chart, but when saving the chart as .png file, they dont appear anywhere.

Comment: Tried drawing the chart and text box to a new bitmap image, and it worked. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a working solution. I still suggest trying the example code as annotations are qite nice!